# Laravel Datetime issue

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datetime

Upon Registration on my laravel website, I can happly register fine however whenever someone's birthday appears to be an older date before 1970 it will always throw an error like this

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (22007)
SQLSTATE[22007]:

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1963-07-17'
>   for column `cp644657_portal`.`users`.`date_of_birth` at row 1 (SQL:
>   insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `address_line_1`, `suburb`,
>   `state`, `post_code`, `date_of_birth`, `mobile`, `position`,
>   `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test Tesy,
>   test@testwrr.tesy, Test, Test, Test, 4151, 1963-07-17, 0400000000, ,
>   $2y$10$H4Ey15q0XqunxuLmziE01OhR3jTEBIHzNJZscA85mQdf88nrYDgEa,
>   2019-07-16 23:11:07, 2019-07-16 23:11:07))

Previous exceptions

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '1963-07-17' for column
>   `cp644657_portal`.`users`.`date_of_birth` at row 1 (22007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to store the data in a TIMESTAMP column.  You will need to change it to DATE or DATETIME for dates before 1970.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

> The **DATE** type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The **DATETIME** type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The **TIMESTAMP** data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: Thank you so much.